# how to set canvas size propertly for canvasTexture in threejs

Tags: three.js

#### This is how I set in my code

```
createText(text = 'example') {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    // canvas.width = 256;
    // canvas.height = 64;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = '#796e8c';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.font='120px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 120);

    const canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);

    const spriteMaterail = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
        map: canvasTexture,
        color: 0xffffff
    });
    const sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterail);
    return sprite;
}
```

#### but the context is clipped

[image]

#### if I set canvas size like:

```
canvas.width = 256
canvas.width = 64
```

the result is like this:

[image]

Comment: Try to apply the width and height of the canvas to the sprite like this: `sprite.scale.set( width, height, 1 );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I set canvas size of canvasTexture in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161789/how-can-i-set-canvas-size-of-canvastexture-in-three-js)